# Is $P_k = \frac{a^k}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{b^k}{(b-c)(b-a)} + \frac{c^k}{(c-a)(c-b)} \ ,\ \ k\in\mathbb{N}$ polynomial for $a, b, c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I met the following problem

> $a$, $b$, $c$ $\in\mathbb{R}$ and not equal each other.
>
> Let $$P_k = \frac{a^k}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{b^k}{(b-c)(b-a)} +
> \frac{c^k}{(c-a)(c-b)}  \ ,\ \  k\in\mathbb{N}$$
>
> Find $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$.

I solved this problem  with factorization and  Synthetic division.

So, I can find $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ not hardly.

$P_1 = 0$, $P_2 = 1$, $P_3 = a+b+c$

In this time, I wonder if $P_4$ is polynomial for $a, b, c$.

As a result, I find $P_4=a^2 + a(b+c) + (b^2 + bc + c^2 )$

$$$$

NOW , I'd like to know  $\color{blue}{\text{if $P_k$ is polynomial for $a, b, c$. }}$

(*Wolframalpha* may say this conjecture is TRUE.)

Is $P_k = \frac{a^k}{(a-b)(a-c)} + \frac{b^k}{(b-c)(b-a)} + \frac{c^k}{(c-a)(c-b)} \ ,\ \ k\in\mathbb{N}$ polynomial for $a, b, c$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bring to a common denominator, and show that each of $a-b$, $b-c$, and $c-a$, viewed as polynomials, divide the numerator..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, let's consider :
$$Q_k(a,b,c)=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)P_k=a^k(b-c)+b^k(c-a)+c^k(a-b) $$

And now consider the polynomial:
$$G(x)=Q_2(x,b,c)=(b-c)\left(x^k-x\frac{b^k-c^k}{b-c}+bc\frac{b^{k-1}-c^{k-1}}{b-c}\right) $$

You can see that $(b-c)$ divides $Q_2(x,b,c)$ and by computing $G(b)$ and $G(c)$ you have $(x-b)(x-c)$ divides $Q_k(x,b,c)$.

As a conclusion $(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$ divides $Q_k$ and hence $P_k=\frac{Q_k}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$ is a polynomial

Comment: +1 Yes. But I think the last term at the end of the $G(x)$ line should be $bc\frac{b^{k-1}-c^{k-1}}{b-c}$

Comment: Thank you for correcting my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Longtime ago I saw your equality studying the function $$f(x)=a^x+b^x-c^x$$ which satisfy the following recurrence for arbitrary $x,h$
$$f(x+3h)=A_hf(x+2h)-B_hf(x+h)+C_hf(x)$$ where $$A_h=a^h+b^h+c^h\\B_h=(ab)^h+(ac)^h+(bc)^h\\C_h=(abc)^h$$ 
When you want to find $f(n)$ for $h=1$ in function of $f(0), f(1),f(2)$,in other words 
solve  $$f(n)=X_nf(2)+Y_nf(1)+Z_nf(0)$$ in which by construction the coefficients are polynomials, you get
$$X_n=\frac{(c-b)a^n-(c-a)b^n+(b-a)c^n}{(c-a)(c-b)(b-a)}$$ which is the same that
 your expression. You have 
$$\color{red}{P_k=\sum_{r+s+t=k-2}a^rb^sc^t}$$
Try to verify this last equality.